# What is different between password lock and PIN lock at Android?

Tags: android

I find that the scree lock include None / Slide / Pattern / PIN/ Password , what is different between password lock and PIN lock at Android?

Thanks!

Comment: This belong in the Android enthusiast stack exchange. http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PIN is a numeric value. A password is an alphanumeric value. It controls what sort of keypad is provided for entering the value (10-digit keypad or a full QWERTY keyboard).

Though, unless you are working on device administration APIs, this is off-topic for Stack Overflow, which is for programming questions.